# how to set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

this may be a dumb question but how do i set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues when trying to pivit in databricks ? im getting this huge error  '`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The pivot column census_block_group has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues to at least the number of distinct values of the pivot column.;`  so anybody know  how do i fix this issue ?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

 val df = censusBlocks.toDF
df.groupBy("B08007e1").pivot("census_block_group").sum("B08008e4")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set it with

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", 10000)
```

Comment: But I have pivot column more than 10000.

Comment: @Salm change the 10000 to the max value you need